# Can't redirect to previous page after using GET

Tags: php, wordpress, session, redirect, plugins

I have a function that is displaying a shopping cart and products, and so after a product is added (which happens via `GET`) I want it to return to regular domain.

This is the code that updates the cart:

```
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

// if the product is added to the cart
if (isset($_GET['add'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']]++;
    header('Location: '.$page);
    // echo 'added';
}
```

Right now the cart is displayed on my homepage, which is `http://localhost/tester/` , and after a product is added the url becomes `http://localhost/tester/?add=1`, but then I want it to revert back to `http://localhost/tester/` but I cannot get it to do that.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's wrong with you putting `header('Location: http://localhost/tester/');`?

Comment: It will be a plugin in the future and I can't know the homepage in advance plus it might not always be on the homepage.

Comment: I just checked and even If i do hardcode it still does not redirect! Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using [parse_url()](https://www.php.net/parse_url)

```
exit(header('Location: '.parse_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],PHP_URL_PATH)));
```

Comment: This seems to do it! It also seems to have fixed another bug I had, where I had the products double on each add.

Comment: I will as soon as it lets me (less then a minute)

Answer (score 1):

Try exploading the URL by "?" and than use the first part for redirect:

```
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

// if the product is added to the cart
if (isset($_GET['add'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']]++;
    $parts = explode("?", $page);
    header('Location: '. $page[0]);
    // echo 'added';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` returning EVERYTHING after the script name. I don't understand why you can't enter in the script name. If you really need that particular method of grabbing the script name, you might try to use `__FILE__` instead of `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`.

Comment: Using `__FILE__` in a MVC type app would just point to the controller not the URL

Comment: Ah, I just saw it in the PHP docs, wasn't really paying attention to what it did.